# Ajax call reset session IIS

Tags: .net, jquery, ajax, iis

I have an issue, for some of my users (IE6,7,firefox etc...), when i'am doing an ajax call ($.post) the session (IIS) is reset.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that for some of your users, the ajax calls happen in a separate session, whereas full page requests continue to happen in their own session? Perhaps your ajax calls are getting a new browser session key assigned?

Comment: @Shan how I can handle this? Thanks!

Comment: I am seeing this exact behavior as well. Non AJAX calls have their own session and AJAX calls have theirs. These two different sessions are killing my application.

Comment: I narrowed my problem down squarely to the fact that Firefox isn't sending the auth cookie when it makes an AJAX call. IE has no problem and no new session is created upon an AJAX call. I'm on FF 9.